# How long did Light's father have to live?

Tags: death-note

Since Light's father took the shinigami eyes, which reduce your lifespan by 1/2, and died the same day, does this mean he only had 2 days left to live?

Comment: Love the question, just think there is no definite answer to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to Use: XLII (from Volume 08):
>
> 1. The use of the DEATH NOTE in the human world sometimes affects other human’s lives or shortens their original life-span, even though
>      their names are not actually written in the DEATH NOTE itself. In
>      these cases, no matter the cause, the god of death sees only the
>      original life-span and not the shortened life-span.

With this, I would say Soichiro had some time to live still, but the use of the death note made his death unnatural.